# How to connect with a Bluetooth device without pairing

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, connection

I'm currently developping my first app in java.

This app requires a direct connection with my BL652, which doesn' t accept any kind of pairing option. That being said, I'm stuck with the code below, which still tries to pair with my bluetooth device instead of just connecting. Therefore, I wanted to know what am i supposed to do in order to make a connection that doesnt require pairing.

Thanks in advance for any response.

```
String mac_address = "DA:72:21:29:0F:F0";
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("E54B0002-67F5-479E-8711-B3B99198CE6C");

lvNewDevices.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(mac_address);

           try {
                socket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
                socket.connect();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: does that device support LE? I think that Bluetooth Classic devices can connect only with pairing

Comment: Its a bluetooth low energy!

Comment: `device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord` is using blueotooth classic. For LE there is totally different way to connect

Comment: Any link or suggestion on how you should do it?

Comment: Have you tried searching? for example, for `android LE connect`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about connection to external hardware but it's definetly possible to connect 2 phones without pairing. I made it using [Android Nearby Connections](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/overview) . And yeah it's basically working with `BLE`. As far as I know it's possible to connect to `RaspberryPi` using that API.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth devices can be made to communicate with each other using master-slave configuration. I first tried with two BLE-HC05s, made one as master and the other as slave, and as expected the master is able to send data, slave is able to receive data, that can be seen using the Serial Monitor in Arduino IDE. I have developed a similar app, which connects to a BLE-HC05 device, sends and receives data. But since you are trying to get data or send data to the App on your phone, Android will not support such unpaired anonymous communications. If you are having trouble with connection or pairing Bluetooth device and your app, I may help you with that. But as far as Bluetooth communication without pairing is concerned, you may not be able to find a way.

Edit: The code to connect any bluetooth device, like BLE-HC06 as you have mentioned, is 1234 (Only if you have not changed it)

Comment: I was able to create a pairing code which works fine with my HC-06. Problem is, every type of only connection feature i tried for my BLE never worked, they will always ask for the passkey which it doesnt have, making it not able to connect (or atlest thats what i think its happening).

Comment: Also, NRF Connect does this feature that im looking foward to, but the source code that is available doesnt show how to make the connection.

Comment: But the main problem is that my BLE doesnt have a passkey, so when I try to connect with my app, It will ask for the passkey to make the connection, but since there isnt one, it wont connect.

Comment: Try 1234, it worked for me. Also you can configure the device to have a certain passkey, using AT commands in Arduino

Comment: 1234 is the passkey i use for my HC-06, which works fine. When i try with my BLE it doesnt tho. Starting to think it still makes a pairing type of connection, but i cant find a way to do it, already tried differents types of sockets or connections, which ended up being a pair type of connection